# Directory not getting created - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

My 'status' flag below is always returning false. And if I remove it then I am getting the error of "ENOENT (No such file or directory)" on the line where I am trying to create the photoFile below.

```
boolean status=false;
File picturesPath = Environment .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File myPicturesFolder = new File (picturesPath.getAbsolutePath() +"/myBuddy");
if(!myPicturesFolder.exists()) {
                status = myPicturesFolder.mkdirs();
               } 


    if(status) {
        File photoFile = null;
        String type = DateAndTimeUtils.getTypeBasedOnTimeOfTheDay();
        String timeStamp = DateAndTimeUtils.dateTimeStamp();
        String photoFileName = type + timeStamp;
        photoFile = File.createTempFile(photoFileName, ".jpg", myPicturesFolder);
     }
```

My permissions in android manifest is also set to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I know what is the problem and where it is happening in my code, but can't seem to understand how to fix it. For some strange reason.
Can someone take a fresh look and please help me?

Comment: what android device version you r using ?

Comment: @SRBbans - My test phone is Android 6.0.1 and minSDKVersion is set to 23 in the androidmanifest

Comment: what is targeted version in ur project ? above android 6 you have to ask at runtime for permissions ?

Comment: So mkdirs()  fails to create a directory. You could have mentioned that to begin with. You are #5 who happens that this werk. You should read this site better.

Comment: @greenapps - Sorry new around here. still finding my way around. Can you point to some relevant answers about mkdirs() failing. I found several about mkdir() but none for mkdirs(); Also my problem is specifically for the "DIRECTORY_PICTURES" subfolder creation. I can create folders elsewhere in my phone... Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause to this problem based on comments above. It was indeed permissions related. Since for Android6, I have to check for permissions status at runtime, the mkdirs() was not working due to no permission. So I added the permissionCheck and onRequestPermissionsResult and it started to work well, thereafter.